# Assets would not Compile in production

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sprockets

I've been trying to precompile assets in production but it just keeps breaking.

I tried

```
  RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

and got:

```
I, [2016-06-22T15:59:02.648161 #1680]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/johndoe/Documents/be/Chak/public/assets/application-3b7afc621ec8ef5d713fe45400021fdd80041418493b774e248da6a1fcfc4052.js
I, [2016-06-22T15:59:02.939980 #1680]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/johndoe/Documents/be/Chak/public/assets/application-3b7afc621ec8ef5d713fe45400021fdd80041418493b774e248da6a1fcfc4052.js.gz
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
JohnDoesMBP:Chak johndoe$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:278:in `sprockets_context'
/Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in `asset_path'
/Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:200:in `font_path'
/Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:140:in `_perform'
```

Anyone have an idea, what's wrong?

My production.rb file looks like this:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.log_level = :debug
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'puma'
gem 'nifty-generators', :group => :development
gem 'table_print'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem 'carrierwave', :github => 'satoruk/carrierwave', :ref => '43179f94d6a4e62f69e812f5082d6447c9138480'
gem 'rmagick', require: false
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'pg'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'paypal-sdk-rest'
gem 'paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'thin'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Heroku you don't need to precompile your own assets, it will be done automatically when you push to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using Heroku, so i don't need to precompile locally either?

Comment: I'm guessing i don't need to add the line you previously mentioned either?

Comment: Actually, Heroku just said the same thing. 
`Error compiling CSS asset`
`No method Error: undefined method '[ ]' for nil:Nil Class`

Comment: the error on the page is `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:278:in 'sprockets_context'`

Comment: So you have not yet been able to push to heroku, and you're getting this error when trying to push your app up to heroku for the first time? Go back and make sure all of your .css files are renamed to .scss

Comment: It allowed me push to heroku, but when the page loaded, i got this error on the screen